# Request timeout com nginx, unicorn e rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, timeout

Tenho uma aplicação em Rails que roda com unicorn em produção. Algumas chamadas levam muito tempo para processar. Eu configurei o servidor para aumentar o timeout, para que o servidor não responda com erro. O problema é que se a requisição demora mais de 30 segundos, eu recebo essa mensagem:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

No `unicorn.rb` tenho `timeout 120` configurado e no nginx.conf tenho:

```
upstream unicorn_my_app {
    server unix:/tmp/my_app.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name www.my_app.com;

        proxy_read_timeout 120;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        root /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;

          if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://unicorn_my_app;
            break;
          }
        }

        error_page 404 500 502 503 504 /erro/erro.html;
        location = /erro/ {
          root /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public;
        }
}
```

Tem alguma outra configuração que eu esqueci?

[Link para a pergunta original em inglês](https://serverfault.com/questions/642705/request-timeout-issue-with-nginx-unicorn-and-rails?noredirect=1#comment775923_642705)

Comment: Tenta aumentar o keepalive_timeout para 120.

Comment: Não funcionou @GuiGS

Comment: Descobri o problema: meu servidor está atrás de um Balanceador de Carga da Rackspace, que coloca timeout de 30s. Usei essas instruções para resolver. https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/89

Answer (score 1):

A configuração usada está correta. O problema nesse caso é que o servidor está atrás de um balanceador de carga na Rackspace, que tem por padrão 30 segundos de timeout. Para mudar esse valor [siga essas instruções](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html). Resumindo, são 2 chamadas de API:

1) Obter um token:

```
curl -s -d \
'{
    "auth":
    {
       "RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":
       {  
          "username": "your_api_username",  
          "apiKey": "your_api_key"}
    }  
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens' | python -m json.tool
```

2) Alterar o timeout do Load Balancer:

```
curl -s -d \ '{"loadBalancer":{
    "timeout": 120
    } }' \
-H 'X-Auth-Token: token_returned_in_last_request' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X PUT \ 'https://iad.loadbalancers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0/<your_customer_id>/loadbalancers/<your_lb_id>'
```